# IText 7 SignatureUtil - signed docs gets "no associate PdfWriter for making indirects"

Tags: itext7

I'm using the latest version of iText7 sign module (7.1.11) to validate digital signatures on pre-existing docs.
In a few cases the SignatureUtil constructor throws a

```
com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: There is no associate PdfWriter for making indirects.
```

Some of the documents for which I receive the exception seem correctly signed as reported by the latest version of Acrobat Reader.
Here is a link to one of these documents:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1biuG9pIOS2piIBLNFNFrV2bhH_U9nk6E/view?usp=sharing

You can try it yourself using a minimal piece of code such as

```
public void test(byte[] fileData) throws IOException {
    try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData);
            PdfReader signedPdfReader = new PdfReader(bais);
            PdfDocument signedPdf = new PdfDocument(signedPdfReader);) {
        SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(signedPdf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## In Short

The cause is an error in the file structure. Already the first of the three document revisions contains an invalid entry in its trailer which caused the processors which created the following two revisions to introduce further errors into the file structure.

## In Detail

Your document contains three revisions.

#### The First, Initial Revision

The first one ends with

```
xref
0 9
0000000000 65535 f 
0000481819 00000 n 
0000481871 00000 n 
0000000017 00000 n 
0000000351 00000 n 
0000000431 00000 n 
0000481637 00000 n 
0000481721 00000 n 
0000481917 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 8/Root 2 0 R/Info 8 0 R/ID [<24348fc363d4c39bd928bff26d44da5c><7bb5325418f976360243700f8e91598d>]>>
startxref
482135
%%EOF
```

The error here is that the **trailer** claims the **Size** is **8**. This entry is specified as

> **Size**
> integer
> *(Required; shall not be an indirect reference)* The total number of entries in the file’s cross-reference table, as defined by the combination of the original section and all update sections. ***Equivalently, this value shall be 1 greater than the highest object number defined in the file.***

*(ISO 32000-1, Table 15 – Entries in the file trailer dictionary)*

In that first revision, though, the cross reference table has entries for object number 0 through ***8*** inclusive, and the trailer even explicitly reference object ***8*** as **Info** dictionary. Thus, the **Size** value should have been **9**.

At first glance this might look harmless but it makes the PDF processors which attach the two signatures fail:

#### The Second Revision (Unreachable Signature)

In the second revision a signing software attempted to add a signature as an incremental update. Due to the **Size** value 8 in the trailer of the first revision, therefore, it assumed that 8 was *1 greater than the highest object number already defined in the file* and, therefore, free for new objects.

Thus, it added an object 8 with a signature field in which this revision eventually was signed. It also referenced object 8 from the **Fields** array of the document **AcroForm** definition.

At the same time, though, it attempted to update the **Info** dictionary. According to the trailer of the first revision that dictionary was in object 8. So it also added an object 8 with the updated **Info** dictionary.

Thus, there now are two objects with number 8 in the second revision but only one can be referenced from the cross references. Due to implementation details of the processor this happened to be the object 8 with the updated **Info** dictionary.

So this second revision contains a signed signature field which isn't reachable from anywhere and the **AcroForm** references the **Info** dictionary as field definition.

As the signature field is not reachable, this revision looks unsigned. As a consequence, this file has again been sent to signing, resulting in the third revision.

#### Third Revision (Reachable Signature)

In the third revision a signing software again attempted to add a signature as an incremental update. As the **Size** entry in the trailer of the second revision is correct, this works alright:

- a new signature field is added in object 11;
- a reference to object 11 is added to the **AcroForm** dictionary **Fields** array which now references objects 8 and 11;
- the revision is signed in the new signature field.

Furthermore, another copy of object 8 with updated **Info** data is added to this revision.

#### iText SignatureUtil Fails Parsing

When instantiating the `SignatureUtil` class for the document with those three revisions, iText attempts to parse the **AcroForm** structure. Here it finds the reference to object 8 and tries to parse it as a field dictionary. This obviously fails, the reachable object 8 after all contains the **Info** dictionary, not a field dictionary.

iText attempts to *complete* this dictionary to become a field dictionary. As you opened the document for reading only, though, this fails with weird exception messages.

## Summary

Essentially a GIGO situation: Garbage in - Garbage out.

The main bug is in the producer of the first revision, some *secPdfProducer Scan Process Machine* according to the original **Info** dictionary. Creating faulty trailer information causes all kinds of havoc.

But also the signing app has a bug: It should not have accepted **Info** data from object 8 in the original revision as there could not have been such an object 8 there.

And there is a minor bug in iText: It should not try to complete "incomplete" fields when parsing the **AcroForm** of a read-only document.